# Using iFrame as a Content Area in an ASP.NET page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I have an ASP.NET website. This site is fairly complex in the sense that it has all sorts of blurs, gradients and rounded corners. The content of the website is always going to be in the same area, an area within some rounded corners. The content is going to be of a dynamic height. And, I can't show any scrollbars, other than those displayed by the browser window.

The banner is a Flash movie. I want to prevent the page from flickering. Because of this, I want to only update the url of the content portion. My question is, is there a way to do this without significant re-working? I thought an iframe would be suitable, but I can't figure out:

1. How to make the iframe's height
   dynamically grow/shrink based on the
   size of the content
2. Get rid of
   the borders / scrollbars across the
   major browsers.

Is what I'm trying possible? Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

1.) You can access the document of the iframe and get the height of the body:  `$("#myiframe").contents().find("body")[0].scrollHeight` and then set that as the iframe's height.

2.) Use `<iframe scrollbar="no" />` and `#myiframe { overflow: visible }`